# Stuck trying to link image in table cells to sql record

Tags: php, html

i have created a table in html, in each cell i would like to link the image in it to a record in php but i'm a bit confused about how to go about it please help.

```
<td>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("server","username","password","db");
$sql = "SELECT imgurl FROM Workshop_products WHERE id=XXX";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<img src="<?php echo $row['imgurl'] ?>" />
</td>
```

Have tried to add something like this to each cell but it only displays the image. thanks

Comment: Protip: don't do that thing you just did the next time you post a question. :P

Comment: Don't mix `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` functions!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the image into an `<a>`-tag:

```
<?php
$link = "user.php?id=$row[id]"; // example: this is the page you want to link to
$img  = $row['imgurl'];
?>

<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to display all the images represented in your database, so maybe this:

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("bt2201-1213.bimserver2.com","ihamzadb","xK56K7S6","ihamzadb");
$sql = "SELECT imgurl FROM Workshop_products";
print "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    print "<td><a href ='" . $row['imgurl'] . "'><img src = '" . $row['imgurl'] . "'></a></td>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Comment: Now when you're fixing his code, why not fix his mix of `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions?

Comment: Oh yeah, I fixed it, I didn't even notice.